Объединить подсписки по одинаковым элементам
Есть вывод списка:
[
    ['Сергей', '+71234567890'],
    ['Сергей', '+71234567810'],
    ['Михаил', '+51234567890'],
    ['Николай', '+72134567890']
]

как сделать так? чтобы было так?
[
    ['Сергей', ['+71234567890','+71234567810'],
    ['Михаил', '+51234567890'],
    ['Николай', '+72134567890']
]

т.е. у кого одинаковые имена и несколько телефонов, создавался вложенный список ?

После форматирования стало очевидно, что у вас во втором коде скобочки синтаксически некорректные, а ещё пихать в одно и то же место (второй элемент списка) два разных типа (строка или вложенный список) — обычно плохая идея

Это задача из степика на словарь.. т.е. мне надо сделать как бы я понял нормализованный список, и потом вывести его через функцию  dict или d = {} просто когда вывожу словарь, то выводится у Сергея один телефон.. не понимаю как сделать ((

так вам словарь нужно получить (что логично) или то, что вы в вопросе написали?

да словарь, ну так как новичек, т.е. теми знаниями списков и срезов без методов. пока..

Как подло получилось — я не смог найти вопрос-дубликат через поиск, потому что я искал по слову «сгруппировать», а в заголовке было написано «сгрупировать»...

да все сделал, вот полный код получился..
lst = ['+71234567890 Сергей', '+71234567810 Сергей', '+51234567890 Михаил', '+72134567890 Николай']


lst_in = []

for x in lst:
    A = [x.split() for x in lst]
print(A)

for x in A:
    x[0], x[1] = x[1],x[0]
    print(x)
    lst_in.append(x)

print(lst_in)

d={}

for i, v in lst_in:
   if i not in d:
       d[i] = []
   d[i].append(v)

print(d)



for i, v in lst_in: -> for v, i in map(str.split, lst):. А всё до него выбросить, кроме двух строк.

map и такую закорючку -> еще не проходил сейчас на степике дошел до словарей.. ))

Закорючка "->" - не часть кода. Слева от неё старый код, справа новый. А map пройти дело не хитрое. Читаете документацию, делаете примеры и готово, пройдено.

а понял, благодарю, ну до map еще не добрался.. сейчас мучаю словари..

C dict.setdefault:
source = [
    ['Сергей', '+71234567890'],
    ['Сергей', '+71234567810'],
    ['Михаил', '+51234567890'],
    ['Николай', '+72134567890']
]

d = {}
for k, v in source:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
target = list(map(list, d.items()))

print(target)


[['Сергей', ['+71234567890', '+71234567810']], ['Михаил', ['+51234567890']], ['Николай', ['+72134567890']]]


Без оного:
source = [
    ['Сергей', '+71234567890'],
    ['Сергей', '+71234567810'],
    ['Михаил', '+51234567890'],
    ['Николай', '+72134567890']
]

d = {}
for k, v in source:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].append(v)

target = list(map(list, d.items()))

print(target)


м-да setdefault я еще не проходил.. пытаюсь как то срезами сделать и циклами)) через подсоединение словаря.. к примеру

@AlexeySinitsky, а вы пройдите.

Сработало !! правда ничего не понял, логику.. те.получается мы перепбрали список если нет в словаре списка то делаем словарь и добавляем туда элементы? так понял ?

Благодарю за ответ)) оч помогли, буду если что-то непонятно, спрашивать.. но сперва мучиться и страдать самостоятельно))

@AlexeySinitsky если вам все-таки нужны словари, то в ответе от @Stanislav Volodarskiy вам нужна будет переменная d, а не target.

@AlexeySinitsky Если ответ вам помог, можете пометить его как принятый. Заодно, можно поставить ответу "плюс".

так вроде разобрался куда нажимать, там галка а где плюс поставить?
